# google script vector math

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering if there is a library that is used for matrix math in Google Scripts. When i google this question, I see that something called "Sylvester" is available for Javascript. Does anybody know if something similar is available for Google Scripts? I'm moving some Matlab code into Google Scripts and I would hate to go back to looping for matrix operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script is Javascript. If you have the code for a math library, paste it in to the editor and it will likely work.